# How to set firebase security rules in order to allow only update of certain fields in document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I would like to know how I can achieve that my user
that has the following fields: uid, friends, notifications, name, username.
Currently my security rules look like this for the user folder

```
function signedIn() {
  return request.auth.uid != null;
}

match /users/{user} {
  allow read, update, write: if signedIn();
}
```

So how can I make a rule for update: "condition",
so that only friends and notifications are updateable,
but not username, uid or name. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [map diffs](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#february_13_2020).

For example:

```
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys()
       .difference("username", "uid", "name"].toSet()).size() === 0;
```

Or shorter:

```
!request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys()
        .hasAny("username", "uid", "name"];
```

Also see:

- The documentation on [map diff operations](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#february_13_2020)
- The documentation o [controlling field access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields).

Comment: So this code would like "protect" the values set for username, uid and name and make them unchangeable ?